# Core Bluetooth unable to discover peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, gatt

I am working with hardware that is in the process of being developed. The board uses a TI CC2541 as the bluetooth chip.

Prior to a test the board is discoverable by two devices and I am able to connect to the board and perform a test where I write and read characteristics (GATT). I perform the test again, everything goes fine until I reconnect to the device and attempt to discover its services. At that point, the board is offline and neither lightblue nor my own app can detect the device. I did a factory reset on one of the iOS devices (iPads) and it is still unable to recognize the board.

Should a factory reset remove all corebluetooth caching that has happened on the device, allowing iOS to re-cache and rediscover the board?

Can this possibly be a corebluetooth problem or a problem with my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to the external peripheral. Factory reset will remove any cached data from the iOS device so as long as the peripheral behaves correctly, the rediscovery should happen as planned. This is all I can tell from the info you shared.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be related to hanging / adding characteristics on a peripheral during development.

I have had a similar issue and instead of clearing the cache on the iOS device, I change the Bluetooth address of the peripheral.  This allows the discovery to work as expected.